# Convert an image to 1 bit monochrome in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, npm, bitmap

I am using bmp-js npm package and sadly the image doesn't convert properly. Not sure what is going on. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
 {
    const bmpBuffer = fs.readFileSync('test3.bmp');
    //var Data = bmp.decode(bmpBuffer);
    const bmpData = {
        data: Data,
        bitPP: 1,
        width: 150,
        height: 150
    };

    const rawData = bmp.encode(bmpData);
    fs.writeFileSync('test/image.bmp', rawData.data);
});
```